# Who was the taxi driver at the beginning of 1Q84?

Tags: haruki-murakami, 1q84

At the very first chapter of Haruki Murakami's 1Q84, Aomame talks with the taxi driver and the latter tells her she can use the emergency stairway to get out of the road.

But right before she exits the taxi, the driver says

> And also please remember: things are not what they seem [...] It's just that you're about to do something *out of the ordinary*. Am I right? People do not ordinarily climb down the emergency stairs of the Metropolitan Expressway in the middle of the day [...] After you do something like that, the everyday *look* of things might seem to change a little. things may look *different* to you than they did before. I've had that experience myself. But don't let appearances fool you. There's always one reality.

From that we can deduce that the driver isn't just any random taxi driver, but someone who knows something about the 1Q84 world.

But, as far as I remember, he is never mentioned or appeared in the book again.

**Who is the taxi driver?**

Comment: I also cannot remember that he re-appears, so Murakami just toys with us. But then again, maybe not every taxi driver is a chekhov’s gun? We'll see if anybody comes up with some real answer to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this answer won't be very satisfying, but:

If you read much Murakami, you soon realize that unexplained plot elements, unfired [Chekhov's guns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chekhov%27s_gun), and mysterious characters who disappear without a trace are central to his style.

In his autobiographical work about writing and running, *What I Talk About When I Talk About Running,* he admits that his plots and characters come to him more-or-less directly from his subconscious, without much intervention or rework.